# ¿Cómo usar una entrada del usuario para salir de un bucle while?

Tags: python

```
    salir = True
    while salir == True:
          .
          .
          .
    opcion = str(input("Quieres seguir? s/n:"))    
    if opcion == "n" or opcion == "N":
        os.system('cls')
        salir = False  #Rompo el while
```

Buenas, quiero que al ingresar otra letra distinta o cualquier cosa me siga pidiendo hasta que ponga una "n" o "N" y si pongo "s" o "S" siga ejecutando el while, ya que si pongo otra cosa el programa se cierra y quiero que eso no pase.
Creo que se podria usar .lower() pero no se de qué manera.

Comment: A ver si entiendo, lo que tu quieres es que solo puedan colocar n, N, s, S y nada mas. Si te colocan algo diferente que vuelva a pedir que ingresen uno. Es correcto?

Comment: Exacto, solo quiero  que puedan colocar  puedan colocar n, N, s, S , de lo   contrario que siga pediendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si interpreto bien tu pregunta, buscas que el usuario solamente pueda introducir ciertos valores a la pregunta, que es parte de un ciclo que se está repitiendo hasta que el usuario decide no continuar más.

La implementación de una pregunta donde solo pueda introducir ciertos valores, la haremos también con un ciclo, por eso el ejemplo a continuación tiene dos ciclos `while`.

El ciclo interno es el que hace la pregunta, pide al usuario su respuesta y no va a salir de allí hasta que ingrese `"S"`, `"s"`, `"N"` o `"n"`, que son los únicos valores permitidos.

El ciclo extereno, es el ciclo principal y se va a repetir hasta que el usuario diga que no quiere continuar, respondiendo `"n"` a la pregunta que se le hace. Si responde `"s"`, continuará en ejecución:

```
while True:
    while True:
        opcion = str(input("¿quieres continuar s/n?")).lower()
        if (opcion!="s" and opcion!="n"):
            print("Opcion inválida, por favor ingrese una opción válida")
        else:
            break

    if opcion=="s":
        print("ok, continuamos, porque tu quieres continuar...")
    else:
        print("ok, salimos y nos vamos...")
        break
```

Si te fijas, ambos son ciclos infinitos `while True` que se *rompen* cuando es apropiado utilizando `break`.

Hay otras formas de lograr el mismo efecto y algunas son más apropiadas que otras en cada caso en particular, lo importante aquí es que comprendas la idea de cómo validar el dato ingresado por el usuario y ya podrás adaptar el código a la situación real que tengas a mano.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Interpretando la pregunta como que quieres que siga en el bucle `while` hasta que se introduzca "n" o "N", la respuesta es:

```
import os

while True:
    print("Seguimos dentro del while")
    opcion = input("Quieres seguir? s/n:") 
    if opcion == "n" or opcion == "N":
        os.system('cls')
        break
```

Sustituye `print("Seguimos dentro del while")` por el código que quieras que se ejecute de forma repetitiva.

Después se pide al usuario que introduzca un valor, que se almacena directamente como string en la variable opcion (no necesitas usar `str()` porque ya es string).

Con `break` sales del bucle `while` si se cumple que `opcion` es `"n"` o `"N"`.

Comment: Creo que no leiste bien la pregunta. Las unicas entradas que acepta es n,N,s,S. La tuya sigue con cualquier cosa que no sea n o N