# Problemas al crear menú de opciones con input()

Tags: python, menu

Quiero hacer un menú de opciones y tengo dudas/problemas de cómo es la forma correcta/óptima de realizarlo.

Código:

```
def menu():
print("--------------------------------------------")
print("ELEGIR OPCION :")
print("1_  ssh_device_1")
print("2_  ssh_device_2")
print("3_  ssh_device_3")
print("4_  ssh_device_4")
print("5_  ssh_device_5")
print("6_ EXIT")
opcion = input("Opcion??---> ")
return opcion

valor = menu()
```

Según la opción elegida ingreso a la función creada para conectarme por ssh usando paramiko

```
if valor== 1:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_1" , "10.164.25.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 2:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_2" , "10.181.2.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 3:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_3" , "10.90.123.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 4:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_4" , "10.90.123.41"] , cmd)

elif valor== 5:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_5" , "10.182.22.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 6:
 print("Bye.....")
```

¿Todas la líneas de código deben estar dentro de la función menu()? ¿O no es necesario? ¿Está bien planteado el formato de menu()?

Probando  la opción 6 -> exit  no me devuelve print("Bye.....").

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El input te devuelve un string y nunca lo conviertes a entero y por eso tu validación está mal, tu función menú está bien  ya que algunas retorna el valor y eso luego lo compruebas

Comment: gracias @christian se me paso ese detalle importante!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero hay que validar la opción ingresada, repitiendo el ingreso hasta obtener una opción aceptable.

Esta opción se ingresa como string, y la retornamos como entero luego de validarla, ya que será más conveniente.

```
def menu():
    while True:
        print("--------------------------------------------")
        print("ELEGIR OPCION :")
        print("1_  ssh_device_1")
        print("2_  ssh_device_2")
        print("3_  ssh_device_3")
        print("4_  ssh_device_4")
        print("5_  ssh_device_5")
        print("6_ EXIT")
        opcion = input("Opcion??---]> ")
        if opcion in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
            return int(opcion)
```

Cada vez que hay datos y acciones repetitivas, es señal de que hay que usar una lista, una tupla o un diccionario, según sea el caso.

En este caso usaremos tuplas de tuplas conteniendos los parametros de conexión para ejecutar el comando. Usamos tuplas pues estos son datos inmutables (supuestamente)

```
conexiones = (
 ("ssh_device_1" , "10.164.25.1"),
 ("ssh_device_2" , "10.181.2.1"),
 ("ssh_device_3" , "10.90.123.1"),
 ("ssh_device_4" , "10.90.123.41"),
 ("ssh_device_5" , "10.182.22.1"))

opcion=menu()
if opcion == 6:
    print("Bye.....")
else:
    funcion_Conectar_ssh(conexiones[opcion - 1], cmd)
```

Comment: genial @Candid Moe siempre me choco con la misma piedra cuando tengo acciones repetitivas, me cuesta tomarle la mano a estos casos de como encararlos! de modo que muchas gracias por tu respuesta y código! saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una forma más profesional de manejarlo es con una estructura de datos que tenga toda la información y crear la funcionalidad a partir de ella. Sugeriría el uso de un diccionario con los datos para hacer más escalable el código.

```
def menu(menu_opts):
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print("ELEGIR OPCION :")
    for key, value in menu_opts.items():
        print(f'{key} - {value[0]}')
    while True: # No saldrá hasta que haya una opcion valida
        opcion = input("Opcion??---> ")
        if opcion in menu_opts:
            return opcion

menu_opts = {'1':["ssh_device_1" , "10.164.25.1"], '2':["ssh_device_2" , "10.181.2.1"],
    '3':["ssh_device_3" , "10.90.123.1"], '4':["ssh_device_4" , "10.90.123.41"],
    '5':["ssh_device_5" , "10.182.22.1"], '6':['Salir', None]}

valor = menu(menu_opts)
dev_list = menu_opts[valor]
if dev_list[1] != None:
    funcion_Conectar_ssh(dev_list, cmd)
else:
    print('Bye...')
```

Puedes agregar y quitar datos del diccionario y el código se adaptará a ello.

Comment: perfecto @aeportugal voy a probar/experimentar con tu código muy interesante solución!  muchas gracias por tu tiempo! saludos

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo primero a tu pregunta:

> ¿Todas la líneas de código deben estar dentro de la función menu()?

Para comenzar, hay que definir bien cual es el comportamiento que esperamos de nuestro programa. Luego dividir en piezas funcionales ese comportamiento y, aunque parezca que no tiene importancia, colocar nombres adecuados a nuestras funciones.

Si una función debe realizar tal o cual tarea, debiera quedar claro solo con ver su nombre. Por esa misma razón, siempre trato de asignar a las funciones nombres que comienzan por un verbo en infinitivo. Eso añade mucha claridad.

Mira, sin ver el código, lo difícil que sería decir qué es lo que tiene que hacer la función `menu()`.

En cambio, si la la función se llamase `mostrarMenu()` o `imprimirMenu()`, podríamos decir que el código luce razonablemente completo.

Pero si la función se llamara `operarMenu()` diría que hace falta el resto del código, además de otras cosas.

Ahora, vamos primero a la definición del comportamiento esperado.

Yo, como usuario, cuando se me presenta un menú, espero poder elegir una opción seguida de otra y otra, hasta que elijo salir del menú (tu menú parece ir en la misma línea, de otra forma no tendría una opción para salir.

Luego, dividamos esto en partes.

Podríamos tener las siguientes funciones,

- Una que se encargue de imprimir el menú en pantalla `imprimirMenu()`,
- Otra que se encargue de interactuar con el usuario para que ingrese una opción y retorne solo hasta que el usuario ingresó una opción válida. Esta se llamará `pedirOpcion()`. Retornará solo si el usuario ha ingresado un número entre 1 y 6, y retornará este valor como un número entero. Para escribir esta función, te invito a leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/447988/21), que te dará los principios de cómo validar lo ingresado por el usuario.
- Otra que se encarga de integrar todo, es decir, llama a una función para imprimir el menú, luego a la función para pedir el valor seleccionado al usuario, luego a las que ejecutan las acciones seleccionadas y repetir todas estas operaciones hasta que el usuario elige salir. Esta se llamará `operarMenuPrincipal()`

No voy a escribir cada función por ti, pero si la principal, basada en tu código, agregando un ciclo para que se repita hasta que el usuario quiera salir.

```
def operarMenuPrincipal():
    opcion = 0
    while (opcion != 6)
        imprimirMenu()
        opcion = pedirOpcion()
        if opcion == 1:
            funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_1" , "10.164.25.1"] , cmd)
        elif opcion == 2:
            funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_2" , "10.181.2.1"] , cmd)
        elif opcion == 3:
            funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_3" , "10.90.123.1"] , cmd)
        elif opcion == 4:
            funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_4" , "10.90.123.41"] , cmd)
        elif opcion == 5:
            funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_5" , "10.182.22.1"] , cmd)
        elif opcion == 6:
            print("Bye.....")
```

Comment: muchas gracias @jachguate por la explicación y tips!

Answer (score 0):

```
def menu():
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print("ELEGIR OPCION :")
    print("1_  ssh_device_1")
    print("2_  ssh_device_2")
    print("3_  ssh_device_3")
    print("4_  ssh_device_4")
    print("5_  ssh_device_5")
    print("6_ EXIT")
    opcion = int(input("Opcion??---> "))
    return opcion

valor = menu()    

if valor== 1:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_1" , "10.164.25.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 2:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_2" , "10.181.2.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 3:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_3" , "10.90.123.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == 4:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_4" , "10.90.123.41"] , cmd)

elif valor== 5:
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_5" , "10.182.22.1"] , cmd)

else
 print("Bye.....")
```

debes convertir el input a entero. o evaluar strings, porque lo que haces es evaluar un string (el input) con un entero (los valores a la derecha del igual del if)

```
valor = menu()    

if valor== "1":
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_1" , "10.164.25.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == "2":
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_2" , "10.181.2.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == "3":
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_3" , "10.90.123.1"] , cmd)

elif valor == "4":
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_4" , "10.90.123.41"] , cmd)

elif valor== "5":
 funcion_Conectar_ssh(["ssh_device_5" , "10.182.22.1"] , cmd)

else
 print("Bye.....")
```

Comment: Gracias  @sanbope  saludos